# Improper Intergral (Fresnel- like)

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Let $\alpha >1$. Show that
$$\int_0^\infty \sin(x^\alpha)\,dx= \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2\alpha}\right) \int_0^\infty e^{-r^\alpha}\,dr.$$

I was going to ask how to do this but figured it out while writing up my questions. So instead I will just give a hint for others who get stuck on it and then someone else or myself can write up a solution if anybody asks.

**Hint:** The contour for the case $\alpha=2$ is the "pie slice" from $0$ to $\pi /4$, with $R\rightarrow \infty$. (fyi in this case the RHS of the equation simplifies since we have half the Gaussian integral). Evaluating the integral along the piece $\theta =\pi/4$ we are able to simplify easily because of this specific value $\theta$.

Comment: A change of variable, a Laplace transform, a residue theorem, a reflection formula for the $\Gamma$ function, profit.

Comment: As an aside, $~\displaystyle\int_0^\infty e^{-r^\alpha}~dr ~=~ \bigg(\frac1\alpha\bigg)! ~=~ \Gamma\bigg(1+\frac1\alpha\bigg).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
\begin{align}
J = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-i \, x^{a}} \, dx.
\end{align}
Let $x = t^{1/a}$ to obtain
\begin{align}
J = \frac{1}{a} \, \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-i t} \, t^{\frac{1}{a} - 1} \, dt.
\end{align} 
Let $u = i t$ to obtain
\begin{align}
J = \frac{1}{a} \left( \frac{1}{i} \right)^{1/a} \, \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-u} \, u^{\frac{1}{a} - 1} \, du
\end{align}
which upon letting $u = x^{a}$ becomes
\begin{align}
J = e^{- \pi i/ 2a} \, \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x^{a}} \, dx. 
\end{align}
Equating both sides yields
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \cos\left( x^{a} \right) \, dx &= \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2 a} \right) \, \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x^{a}} \, dx \\
\int_{0}^{\infty} \sin\left( x^{a} \right) \, dx &= \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2 a} \right) \, \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x^{a}} \, dx
\end{align}

Comment: wow, very nice. Thanks.